# Why does debugger break on /***/ }),

Tags: typescript, angular9

I am trying to run the Angular "get started" app.  I am running it in VS Code.  When I run the app the debugger stops on the line of code shown below and I am wondering why.

Steps to reproduce:

Download the demo app from [this link](https://stackblitz.com/angular/odpeknvxnlq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).
(I couldn't find the download button either.)

Unzip the file

run npm install

run ng serve

fix angular.json - add src/ to typescript file ref

run ng update -all  see package.json below

run ng serve

start debugging in visual studio code

debugger breaks on this line:

```
/***/ }),
```

I don't see an error message... what does this mean?
The tab in VS Code says the file is main.js and it is located at localhost:4200\main.js  - where ever that may be.

```
{
  "name": "odpeknvxnlq.angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "rxjs": "6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2",
    "jasmine-core": "3.5.0",
    "@angular/core": "9.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "9.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "9.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "9.1.1",
    "jasmine-marbles": "0.6.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "9.1.1",
    "@angular/animations": "9.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "9.1.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.10.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.10",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.3",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.8.2",
    "tslint": "~6.1.1",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of that line? Maybe you just accidentally set a breakpoint?

Comment: @JensV I'm trying to figure out how to post an image.  In the meantime, I checked again and there is no breakpoint.

Comment: You can just paste if you have an image in the clipboard

Comment: By "Break" do you mean it just stops execution there and you can choose to continue or does it stop working alltogether?

Comment: @JensV Stops execution and I can continue.  Does not appear to be a bug... I dont see any output in output, terminal or debug console window.

Comment: Possibly related to this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug/issues/690

Comment: @JensV image added

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same issue as you with no apparent solution. Here's how I got Chrome to stop breaking on that line: I edited my `main.ts` file and added/removed some carriage returns just to force the next "ng serve" to rebuild this file. I suspect it is related to some sort of caching that we cannot directly affect by adding/removing breakpoints.

**Note:** The github.com/microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug/issues/690 link mentioned by @JensV in the comments is dead. Perhaps it explained or offered a better way to stop this problem from happening.

**Edit:** Here's the solution. VSCode will apparently stop execution in debug mode if you have any *unbound breakpoints*. It also does not log a trace event for this behavior (or, at least, anything obvious). I filed a bug report with GitHub which helped me get to the bottom of it: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/119909

Comment: After touching the main.ts file, the issue eventually came back. Aargh. What a pain!

Comment: @Chris: While this answer included a lot of commentary, it also included a solution, which was edited into the answer before your review. To avoid confusion, I'd edited the answer to remove the unnecessary commentary, and better emphasize the suggestions.